# How to extract part of a mp3 title (string) to name a new tag in mp3tag with Regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the specified keys of a song each included in many mp3 files, using the [mp3Tag](https://help.mp3tag.de/index.html) program.

The number of characters to the left of the Musical key in the mp3 filnames is constant (29 characters), so I succeeded in cutting it with the `$left(x,n)` function imbedded in the `$regexp(x,expr,repl)` function.

But my specific problem is the variable number of characters to the right of the Musical Key - since it is variable I cannot use the `$right(x,n)` function effectively. I tought of using the combinations of functions `$len(x)` and`$right(x,n)` to substract the Musical Key from the remaining string but can't see how to do it with a variable number of character to the right of the Musical Key.

The whole Point is to **have a clean Tag column with all the keys per track** (without remaning all the collection manually one by one :)).
I scanned the functions given here, but I can't see which combination of those other functions would work to cut the variable number of characters to the right of the Musical Keys:

(mp3tag function - [String functions](https://help.mp3tag.de/main_scripting.html)

### My question:

**How do I do that with other functions or a whole different simpler approach?**

So far I did cut the constant 29 characters to the left of the Musical key in the mp3 filname with the help of:

**Tag - Tag** (Convert Wizard)

`$regexp(x,expr,repl)` (mp3tag function - [String functions](https://help.mp3tag.de/main_scripting.html)

`$left(x,n)` (mp3tag function - idem)

`$right(x,n)` (mp3tag function - idem)

For example:

Wanted result (extracted **D**, **A**, **G** Musical Keys in a new **Keys** Tag Column):

`D`

`A`

`G`

from filenames:

510 - Sonata for keyboard in **D** minor, K. 517 (L. 266).mp3

026 - Sonata for keyboard in **A** major, K. 26 (L. 368).mp3

031 - Sonata for keyboard in **G** minor, K. 31 (L. 231).mp3

### 1st operation Tag - Tag ($left(x,n) function):

Cut the first 29 characters 
(relpaces: **031_-_Sonata_for_keyboard_in_** by blank (**' '**)
using the embeded `$left(x,n)` function in the `$regexp(x,expr,repl)` function:

[image]

As follows:

Used functions:

`$regexp(x,expr,repl)`

`$left(x,n)`

// Embedding of functions

`$regexp(x,`**$left(x,n)**`,repl)`

// String assignation (parameter String in the `$left(x,n)` function)

`$regexp(x,$left(`**%initialkey%**`,n),repl)`

// Statement of the numbers of caracters to cut/void from 1st to the Musical Key's character (D, A, G, etc.)(same number for all the mp3 files (29 characters))

`$regexp(%initialkey%,$left(%initialkey%,`**29**`),' ')`

// String assignation (parameter String in the `$regexp(x,expr,repl)` function)

`$regexp(`**%initialkey%**`,$left(%initialkey%,29),repl)`

// Voiding/cutting replacing with no character parameter of regexp function 
(`' '` voiding string replacement parameter in the `$regexp(x,expr,repl)` function)

`$regexp(%initialkey%,$left(%initialkey%,29),`**' '**`)`

Thanks a lot for your help!

Ref. used:

[Mp3Tag - Replace with regular expression](http://help.mp3tag.de/options_format.html#regexp)

[Scripting functions](http://help.mp3tag.de/main_scripting.html)

[Second, Third, … Occurences Of String](https://community.mp3tag.de/t/second-third-occurences-of-string/13990)

[Extract title part for track no.](https://community.mp3tag.de/t/extract-title-part-for-track-no/12148/2)

[Convert Tag-Tag](https://community.mp3tag.de/t/convert-tag-tag/13249/3)

[Open MenuHow to Use Mp3Tag to Edit Audio Files by xephyx](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Use-Mp3Tag-to-Edit-Audio-Files/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following simpler way using the free program [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/method_replace)

It has a cool built-in Remove function and even an amazing Javascript Script editor.

The Solution I used:

Basically:

To keep things simple and spare using a script for this operation, I inputed 100 characters to remove, starting 1 index/position after the Musical Key. I put an arbitrary 100 characters to remove as all the mp3 files titles had less than 100 characters following the Musical Key.
If for your case it has more, input 1000 :) !

Here are the pics of the process:

**1st Step. Removal of the firs 29 characters**

[image: 1st Step. Removal of the firs 29 characters]

**1st Step Result**

[image: 1st Step Result]

**2nd Step. Removal of all characters succeeding the Musical Key**

[image: 2nd Step. Removal of all characters succeeding the Musical Key]

**2nd Step result**

[image: 2nd Step result]

here the guide of Advanced Renamer other cool Renaming methods:
[Renaming Methods](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/method_replace)